# spacing between paragraphs in beamer

Tags: beamer, paragraphs

Is there any way to increase spacing between paragraphs in `beamer` without doing it manually in each paragraph?

I don't want to write `\medskip`, or other command manually all time (ok, if there's no choice I will, but...)

I also tried with `\setlength{\parskip}{number of mm}` in the preamble. That seemed nice to me but nothing happened.

And I don't want to itemize all my documents.

So, any suggestions?
Thanks!

EDIT: Here there's a sample code. I used `\setlength{\parskip}{8mm}` in preamble and it doesn't work. Also tried moving it just after `begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\title{Title}
\author {MyName}
\institute{MyInstitute}
\date {\today}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definici\'on}
\newtheorem{ejem}{Ejemplo}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corolario}

\setlength{\parskip}{8mm}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

\end{frame}

\section{Testing}

\begin{frame}

hello world\\

bye world\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\parskip` is the correct approach. Try to give the number including a unit, e.g. `\setlength{\parskip}{2cm}`

Comment: If `\setlength{\parskip}{<len>}` doesn't work in your preamble, please provide us with something that replicates your behaviour. You must be doing something different. As a last resort, attempt putting `\setlength{\parskip}{<len>}` just after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I edited the post with a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using `\\`. If you want a new paragraph use an empty line (or in the few occasions, this is not an option use `\par`)

```
\begin{frame}
hello world

bye world
\end{frame}
```

For an undoubtedly quote on this topic see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=30805381#30805381